# Error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, typeerror

I am trying to batch process KML polygons from a folder into a temp geodatabase.
From there, Iif this works and runs then I am trying to Append the polygons to result to a Server connection (Postgres withe append layer). Going to use here the ModelBuilder when the script runs. 
But I am stuck on a error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Bjorn.tenBroeke\Documents\Bjorn\KML.py", line 20, in 
>           for kml in arcpy.ListFiles('*.KM*'):
>       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>       Failed to execute (Script).

```
# Name: BatchKML_to_GDB.py
# Description: Converts a directory of KMLs and copies the output into a single fGDB.
#              A 2 step process: first convert the KML files, and then copy the featureclases

# Import system models
import arcpy, os

# Set workspace (where all the KMLs are)
arcpy.env.workspace= (r"C:\DATA\KML")

# Set local variables and location for the consolidated file geodatabase
outLocation = "C:/WorkingData/fGDBs"
MasterGDB = 'AllKMLLayers.gdb'
MasterGDBLocation = os.path.join(outLocation, MasterGDB)

# Create the master FileGeodatabase
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outLocation, MasterGDB)

# Convert all KMZ and KML files found in the current workspace
for kml in arcpy.ListFiles('*.KM*'):
  print "CONVERTING: " + os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,kml)
  arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(kml, outLocation)


# Change the workspace to fGDB location
arcpy.env.workspace = outLocation

# Loop through all the FileGeodatabases within the workspace
wks = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*', 'FileGDB')
# Skip the Master GDB
wks.remove(MasterGDBLocation)

for fgdb in wks:  

  # Change the workspace to the current FileGeodatabase
  arcpy.env.workspace = fgdb    

  # For every Featureclass inside, copy it to the Master and use the name from the original fGDB  
  featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*', '', 'Placemarks')
  for fc in featureClasses:
    print "COPYING: " + fc + " FROM: " + fgdb    
    fcCopy = fgdb + os.sep + 'Placemarks' + os.sep + fc    
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fcCopy, MasterGDBLocation, fgdb[fgdb.rfind(os.sep)+1:-4])


# Clean up
del kmz, wks, fc, featureClasses, fgdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the workspace folder/directory does not exist (r"C:\DATA\KML").  Check to make sure the "KML" folder/directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the folder you are calling ListFiles() in has no files matching your wildcard search.

Consequently it is returning None.

Alternatively, try changing:

```
arcpy.env.workspace= (r"C:\DATA\KML")
```

to:

```
arcpy.env.workspace= r"C:\DATA\KML"
```

Comment: No error should show if the folder/directory does not contain any like files.

Comment: @artwork21 I cannot test at the moment but I would expect 'for x in None:' to throw the same error.

Comment: I just tested, no error.